# How to remedy this situation, user self answers then deletes answer

Tags: discussion, support, self-answer, self-delete

A newish (2 months) user asked a question. It was answerable it seemed, even garnished an upvote from a viewer.

Here is the question: [Trigger Similar JQuery element on different span element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979078/trigger-similar-jquery-element-on-different-span-element)

About an hour later, the user posted an answer to the question. However, minutes after posting the answer, they deleted it (10k+ only can view it). The answer does seem to solve their issue (although since it was very specific to the situation it is hard to tell if it is really valuable to others).

I saw this scenario, and was kind of baffled. What is the right course of action, if any, to take when this is observed?

Comment: Probably ask to the OP for the reason behind it.

Comment: @hims056 - I politely asked him if the answer was the solution to undelete it.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian - I believe he could have still deleted the question (even though there was an answer, it would not prevent deletion unless it had an upvote). He definitely can delete his own answer, but I am curious if he did so because he was unsure of self answering.

Comment: Problem solved - he's undeleted it.

Comment: @slugster: I'd vote to close this as "no longer reproducible", but I guess the general question still stands, even if this specific instance has been resolved.